# How to stop overlapping panels to become children of each other?

Tags: vb.net, panel, overlap

**Scenario**
I have 3 panels which are to be shown depending upon the choice from combobox.
Each panel is designed in exact location, and all three are exactly overlapping each other and even may be partially. But their Top and Left properties are same.

**Problem**
As soon as I drag to position the panel, it becomes child of one of other two.
I have checked it through .parent.name 
If I hide one panel say pnlRSB1 then the child of it the pnlRSB2 also vanishes.

*Though I have solved the problem using recursive loop, but I want to know the other available options.*

Is there a way that I may tell IDE, "hey don't make it child of underlying panel, its independent"?

B.T.W if someone wants the loop thing solution, I will provide that as well, but I hate recursion though I am living with it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not drag them.  Just add all three `Panels` to the form somewhere.  Drag one of them so that it's `Location` and `Size` are what you want and then set the other two to have he same values via the Properties window.

By the way, one `Panel` will only become a child of another if you drop it within the other's bounds.  The parent will be whatever control is under the mouse pointer when you drop.

Also note that you can still easily access each `Panel` in the designer, even if they are in the same `Location` and have the same `Size`.  You just have to change the z-order so that the one you want to access is at the front.  There are a number of ways to do that.

1. Right-click on the `Panel` you can see and select `Send to Back`. Repeat until the `Panel` you want to access is in front.
2. Open the Properties window and select the `Panel` you want to access in the drop-down list at the top.  This will draw a selection rectangle around the `Panel` even if the `Panel` itself is obscured.  Right-click the selection rectangle and select `Bring to Front`.
3. Open the Document Outline window and either drag the `Panel` you want to access up above the others in the tree or select it and use the tool bar to move it up.  The order of the child controls in the tree matches the z-order.

Comment: Thanks very much it solved the problem. 
I select the required panel from properties dropdown list.

One more, is it possible to have control Array like panels(cboMethod.selectedIndex).Show() :)

Comment: Designer support for controls arrays doesn't exist in VB.NET as it did in VB6 because it isn't required. The reason for it in VB6 is to handle events for multiple controls with a single method. That is done by adding multiple controls to a single `Handles` clause in VB.NET, which can be done via the Properties window or manually in code. An array of controls is just like any other array in VB.NET, so it is created in code like any other array.